# Base64 to PDF file fails

Tags: python, pdf, base64

I'm trying to write a Base64 string to a PDF file. But the PDF file is corrupt.
The Base64 is coming from a webrequest.

I have tried this:

```
blob = js_response.get("result")
with open("test.txt, "w") as txtfile:
    txtfile.write(blob)
with open("test.pdf", "w") as pdffile:
    pdffile.write(blob)
```

The reason I write it to a TXT file first is for debugging. The code does write 2 files:
When I open the TXT file and test it on a base64 to PDF converter like base64.guru, the right PDF file is opened.

But when I try to open the PDF file, the file is corrupt.

The most odd thing is, this exact same code was working last week. So I don't think it has something to do with the write command, but more on the format of the Base64?

Thanks for any insights

Comment: PDF is a binary format, writing in text mode will probably cause problems. Use binary mode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this

```
import base64

blob = js_response.get("result")

# Decode the base64 string to binary data
pdf_binary = base64.b64decode(blob)

# Write binary data to a PDF file
with open("test.pdf", "wb") as pdffile:
    pdffile.write(pdf_binary)
```